# how to verify that my validator has the right session keys

Tags: api, session

I want to write a sanity check that my node has the right session keys configured, based on the stash address:

```
  let nextKeys = await api.query.session.nextKeys(stash_account);
  console.log(`Node's next keys: ${nextKeys}`);
  console.log(`Node's next keys in hex: ${nextKeys.toHex()}`);
  let nodeHasKeys = await api.rpc.author.hasSessionKeys(nextKeys.toHex());
  console.log(`Node has keys: ${nodeHasKeys}`);
```

The above always returns False, but it looks like I am getting the right data from the chain (`{"grandpa":"0x90cac` etc...).

How to make the above work? I tried `hasSessionKeys(nextKeys)` as well without `.toHex()` but it didn't work either.

I am trying on Kusama but I'd like the above to work on Polkadot too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replying to myself. It actually works the way I described it, not sure why I thought otherwise initially.

```
  let nextKeys = await api.query.session.nextKeys(stash_account);
  let nodeHasKeys = await api.rpc.author.hasSessionKeys(nextKeys.toHex());
  if (nodeHasKeys.isFalse()) {
    console.error(`Node does not have the expected session keys.`);
  }
```

Here is a complete session key check script:
https://github.com/midl-dev/polkadot-k8s/blob/master/polkadot-session-key-check/index.ts